# Appending adding and reading regedit with custom vb.net buttons

Tags: vb.net, append, regedit

I have 26 buttons on my form (each a letter of the alphabet) I want to press a button lets say Z and that it then changes the relevant registry key value of 0 to 1 representing the button has already been clicked (these a-z buttons are to be compared with on/ off switches). This way if I start my program up again the values in the regedit will “memorize" which buttons were turned on and which were turned off in our previous program session.

Ultimately the buttons turned off should always appear as red until switched on again.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Please see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints about asking *good* questions.

Comment: sure fine heres one for you http://www.funadvice.com/q/im_wierd_help_me

Comment: Don't store program settings in the registry.  Use application settings (in particular, user-scoped settings) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx

Comment: Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sykcb9xf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the Platform or Language you are working on , there are options called Settings , Which save all the information of what you worked on application and retrieve them back when the application has started again,

As i am familiar with C# , [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Helps you if you're working on C#. For other platforms, try to google out how are these used.

Cheers, 
Vivek